# Looping through files in directory with Dir function, just hits same file over and over

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that looks through several other spreadsheets in a given directory to extract some statistics from them.  So far, it gets to the first file and just hits it over and over again.

My code goes something like this:

```
Public Sub GetResults()
    Const strDirectory As String = "SomeNetworkLocation"
    Dim strFileName As String

    strFileName = Dir(strDirectory & "*.xl??")

    Do While strFileName <> ""

        If strFileName Like "SomeMatchingScheme_##_??"
            Workbooks.Open strDirectory & strFileName

            'Do stuff with the workbook

            Workbooks(strFileName).Close
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call again

```
strFileName = Dir  ' with no parameters
```

before loop. This call will iterate strFileName to the next file. Without it, it will stick to the first found file.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.